How can I import xgmml cytoscape networks into a new session file such that style formatting can be applied?
I am attempting to consolidate several networks from across several Cytoscape sessions into a new session file for publication purposes. The goal is to export my list of individual networks from the respective source *.cys sessions and import them as fully editable networks with layout and style retained. I exported the original networks as *.xgmml files (with style info) and imported them into a new *.cys session. Style changes (e.g. border color, etc) can be modified for the first imported network, but all subsequent imported networks appear to be locked to style changes. (This happens irrespective of import to the same network collection or a new network collection.) Is there a fix / workaround?

Yes, as you noted, when you bring in an XGMML file, the style properties often come in a "locked".  Actually, the first one should also have been "locked".  You can remove the locked attributes by selecting the node or all nodes and then right-clicking on the bypass column and doing a "remove bypass".  My suggestion, however, would be to export the styles "File->Export->Styles to File" and just name them different things.  I think that will get you more of what you want.
